# Angular: Get ViewChildren inside of directive

Tags: angular, directive, viewchildren

I have a component called `SomeComponent`. This component contains some Elements like a paragraph which has a template reference variable attached to it. Here is an example of `SomeComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: "some-component",
  template: ` <p #isValid>Hello from Component</p> `
})
export class SomeComponent {
}
```

I use `SomeComponent` in my `AppComponent`.
Now I want to have a Directive attached to `SomeComponent` that gets all Elements of `SomeComponent` that have the `#isValid` template reference variable.

My approach was using ViewChildren inside of the Directive for this. Here is an example of the directive.

```
@Directive({ selector: "[getIsValid]" })
export class GetIsValidDirective implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChildren("isValid") isValidChildren: QueryList<unknown>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("isValidChildren defined?", this.isValidChildren);

    this.isValidChildren?.changes.subscribe((next) =>
      console.log("isValidChildren changes", next)
    );
  }
}
```

`SomeComponent` and `GetIsValidDirective` are used in the `AppComponent` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: ` <some-component getIsValid></some-component> `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

I expected to get all Elements that hasl `isValid` attached to it inside the `GetIsValidDirective`. But `this.isValidChildren` is always undefined.

Am I missing something obvious here or is this just not possible because the directive has no access to the inner view of `SomeComponent`?

Comment: the template variable is in the `SomeComponent` so you need to query `SomeComponent` and then loop over the instances of `SomeComponent` and check for `isValid` property

Comment: yep that would work. So if I had the requirement to have the ViewChildren query inside the directive, my answer would be this is technically not possible right?
I cant find such a statement in the Angular Docs

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there is a solution but the end goal is not clear